# Tensorflow Gradient Optimizer returning Nan, while cross entropy cost returns a number

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf_X = tf.placeholder("float",[None,3073])
tf_Y = tf.placeholder("float",[None,10])
tf_W = tf.Variable(0.001*tf.random_normal([3073,10]))

#tf.random_uniform([3073,10],-0.1,0.1)#
tf_learning_rate = 0.0001

hypothesis = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf_X,tf_W)) #out put is softmax value for each class

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf_Y*-tf.log(hypothesis), reduction_indices=1))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(tf_learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()



with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {tf_X:X_dev,tf_Y:onehot_y_dev})
    print sess.run
    for step in xrange(400):

        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {tf_X:X_dev,tf_Y:onehot_y_dev}) # we have to make one hot coding for y
        if step % 200 ==0:
            print step,sess.run(cost, feed_dict={tf_X:X_dev,tf_Y:onehot_y_dev})
```

I'm trying to implement softmax-cross entropy in tensorflow.
When I sess.run(cost) it returns a number (2.322)
but when I run the GradientDescentOptimizer, the cost returned is Nan...
What's happening here? Did I implement the optimizer function wrong?

Answer (score 0):

O.K I found the problem by myself.
I always heard of exploding gradients but the problem here is about exploding costs. I did not know there is a exploding cost problem

After my first gradident descent, my high learning rate forced my cost to explode by becoming -log(number very close to zero).
If you have a same problem as I had, lower your learning rate, or use tf.clip to mitigate this type of problem